# Anonymous class instance placement

Tags: java, coding-style, sun-coding-conventions

Where do you place instance of anonymous class?

```
public class MyClass {
    // Variables
    private Api api;

    // Functions
    public void callApi() {
        api.get(<...>, responseListener)
    }

    // Where to put that? Top of the file, bottom, next to function?
    private ResponseListener responseListener = new ResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object response) {
        }
    };
}
```

And also, in that case, would it be preferable to instantiate directly in the api call?

```
    public void callApi() {
        api.get(<...>, new ResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object response) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In your second version you are creating new instance of `ResponseListener` each time you invoke `callApi`. In first version you are reusing already created instance.

Comment: The first snippet declares an instance variable, and initializes it with an instance of an anonymous inner class. I would put it with all the other instance variable declarations: at the top of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a decision that you get to make. The way you wrote it originally, you have a field called `responseListener` that gets initialized once and reused on each `callApi()` invocation. If that's the behavior you want, you could put it above the `callApi()` method (with the other field, `api`). Or leave it where it is. They're both ok, it's just which do you prefer.

If, however, you want a new instance each time `callApi()` is invoked, then it would make sense to put it inside `callApi()`.

So it matters whether you put it inside `callApi()` or outside, but only you can decide which is better. And if you want it outside, it doesn't matter where outside, and again only you can decide which is better.

Comment: I couldn't find many recent [documents](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) about variable placement. But in case of anonymous class, it seems to be based on coder's need and/or preference.